# Drupal 7: hook_menu not working correctly

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I've created a custom module (called page_arg) simply for the purpose of registering a path and having it use a certain template file. I had this working with Drupal 6, but can't get it to work in Drupal 7. Basically, if I leave the page_arg_callback() function in the module, I get a 500 Server Error on every page in the site. If I remove it, I'm able to visit the path I'm trying to register, but it isn't using the template file I want it to use.

```
function page_arg_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['flashcards'] = array(
    'title' => 'Flashcards',
    'page callback' => 'page_arg_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function page_arg_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $url = urlSplit(); //custom function. trust me, this isn't the problem :)
    if($url[0] == 'flashcards'){
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'flashcards';
    }
}

function page_arg_callback($arg){
  return 'howdy';
}
```

As a secondary question, is this the best way to go about simply registering a path and pointing it to a template file? Seems a bit elaborate. Could I implement hook_menu() in my theme instead?

Comment: The code above didn't display an error on my installation (except for the urlSplit). The code in my answer is a sort-of reply to your last question as well, it's better to use hook_theme to point a callback to a template file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function page_arg_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['flashcards'] = array(
    'title' => 'Flashcards',
    'page callback' => 'page_arg_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function page_arg_callback() {
  // Do stuff
  return theme('page_arg');
}

function page_arg_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'page_arg' => array(
      'template' => 'page-arg',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'page_arg') . '/theme/templates',
    ),
  );
}
```

Create a file *page-arg.tpl.php* and put it in /theme/templates in your module (page_arg) directory.